# Recommended config for pagespeed reverse proxy server with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, reverse-proxy, mod-pagespeed

I'd like to setup server to use pagespeed reverse proxy server with apache for several sites which cannot run pagespeed on their origin. It seems I should be able to create a `VirtualHost` for each site and use `ModPagespeedMapProxyDomain` to specify the origin server. I haven't been able to get this to work. Here's what I have so far.

- `http://origin.example.com/` is the web server for all dynamic and static content. It does not run pagespeed.
- `http://www.example.com/` will be the pagespeed server configured as a reverse proxy. No files are hosted here.

I've installed `mod-pagespeed-stable-1.9.32.4-7251.x86_64` for CentOS and am using the default config from `/etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf` except with `CoreRules` enabled—[see my config](http://hastebin.com/jeroludahe).

I then added a VirtualHost directory:

```
<VirtualHost 111.222.333.444:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    <IfModule pagespeed_module>
        ModPagespeed On
        ModPagespeedMapProxyDomain www.example.com origin.example.com
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now any requests to http://www.example.com/ results in an empty page with a `403 Forbidden` header:

```
[q@localhost ~] curl -I http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
[…]
```

The request is logged to the global `access_log`, but there are no messages in `error_log` (does MPS have its own error log?). I am able to access `http://www.example.com/pagespeed_global_admin` but there is no indication there of errors.

If I remove the `ModPagespeed*` config and set up the vhost as a proxy using `ProxyPassReverse / http://origin.example.com/`, the site loads fine. However, of course, pagespeed doesn't take effect.

Can you see what I've done wrong? What is the recommended way to setup a pagespeed reverse proxy?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the configuration I found that fulfilled my requirements.

Indeed, use of *mod_proxy* is required, because *mod_pagespeed* does not have the ability to actually proxy requests. This VirtualHost config works to receive requests for www.example.com as a proxy for content served by another server at origin.example.com. Uncomment the `ModPagespeedEnableFilters` lines to enable specific PageSpeed features. You can view the PageSpeed admin at www.example.com/pagespeed_admin.

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    CustomLog /home/example/logs/access_log combined
    ErrorLog /home/example/logs/error_log
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPass /pagespeed_admin !
        ProxyPass /logs/ !
        ProxyPass / http://origin.example.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://origin.example.com/
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain origin.example.com www.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule pagespeed_module>
        ModPagespeed On
        ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain www.example.com origin.example.com
        ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain example.com origin.example.com
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters add_head
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_heads
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_import_to_link
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters outline_css
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters outline_javascript
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_above_scripts
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_to_head
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters fallback_rewrite_css_urls
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_style_attributes
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_style_attributes_with_url
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters flatten_css_imports
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters make_google_analytics_async
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript_external
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript_inline
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters include_js_source_maps
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters canonicalize_javascript_libraries
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_css
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_google_font_css
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_javascript
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters local_storage_cache
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_progressive
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_webp
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_to_webp_lossless
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_image_dimensions
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_jpeg
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_png
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_webp
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_gif_to_png
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters strip_image_color_profile
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters strip_image_meta_data
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_rendered_image_dimensions
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_preview_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_mobile_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache_css
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache_scripts
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache_pdfs
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters sprite_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_domains
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters trim_urls
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters pedantic
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_quotes
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters add_instrumentation
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_meta_tags
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters defer_javascript
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters dedup_inlined_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch
        #ModPagespeedEnableFilters in_place_optimize_for_browser
    </IfModule>
    <Location /pagespeed_admin>
        AuthName "PageSpeed Admin"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /home/example/etc/htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        Satisfy any
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```